# Grouping people in pandas dataframe with customized function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, distance

**Introduction:**
I have a pandas dataframe with people who live in different locations (latitude, longitude, floor number). I want to cluster 3 people each in one group. This means, at the end of this process, every person is assigned to one particular group.  My dataframe has the length of multiples of 9 (e.g 18 people).

The *tricky* part is, people in the same group are not allowed to have same location in terms of latitude and longitude.

**What is going wrong?**
After I apply my function to the pandas dataframe, I get a new dataframe in which the people are assigned to groups. However, there are 2 problems:

1) Each time 3 people are *not* assigned to a group! I don't know why and I don't know if this is the reason for my second problem.

2) For some reasons, which are not clear to me, people with same location (latitude/longitude) are grouped together! Remember, this should never happen.

**Here is what I did:**

(link to [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EDjZ97mOu1qYU3ZzocuaXWerPUdTqMrK))

Import library:

```
from math import atan2, cos, radians, sin, sqrt
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import random
```

Get the data:

```
array_data=([[ 50.56419  ,   8.67667  ,   2.       , 160.       ],
   [ 50.5740356,   8.6718179,   1.       ,   5.       ],
   [ 50.5746321,   8.6831284,   3.       , 202.       ],
   [ 50.5747453,   8.6765588,   4.       , 119.       ],
   [ 50.5748992,   8.6611471,   2.       , 260.       ],
   [ 50.5748992,   8.6611471,   3.       , 102.       ],
   [ 50.575    ,   8.65985  ,   2.       , 267.       ],
   [ 50.5751   ,   8.66027  ,   2.       ,   7.       ],
   [ 50.5751   ,   8.66027  ,   2.       ,  56.       ],
   [ 50.57536  ,   8.67741  ,   1.       , 194.       ],
   [ 50.57536  ,   8.67741  ,   1.       , 282.       ],
   [ 50.5755255,   8.6884584,   0.       , 276.       ],
   [ 50.5755273,   8.674282 ,   3.       , 167.       ],
   [ 50.57553  ,   8.6826   ,   2.       , 273.       ],
   [ 50.5755973,   8.6847492,   0.       , 168.       ],
   [ 50.5756757,   8.6846139,   4.       , 255.       ],
   [ 50.57572  ,   8.65965  ,   0.       ,  66.       ],
   [ 50.57591  ,   8.68175  ,   1.       , 187.       ]])

all_persons = pd.DataFrame(data=array_data) # convert back to dataframe

all_persons.rename(columns={0: 'latitude', 1: 'longitude', 2:'floor', 3:'id'}, inplace=True) # rename columns
```

This is the function to calculate the distance between the people. If distance equals 0, people have same location in terms of latitude and longitude.

```
def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, floor_person_1, floor_person_2):
    """
    Calculate the shortest distance between two points given by the latitude and
    longitude.
    """
    scattering_factor = 0.0001

    earth_radius = 6373  # Approximate / in km.
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = earth_radius * c  # Unit: km. Parameter does not consider floor number
    print(distance)

    # people share same location (latitude / longitude) but on different floors 
    # --> its ok to put them in same group
    if (distance==0) and (floor_person_1 != floor_person_2): 
      distance = distance + scattering_factor
      print('Identical location but different floors')
      print('lat1:', math.degrees(lat1), 'lon1:', math.degrees(lon1))
      print('lat2', math.degrees(lat2), 'lon2:', math.degrees(lon2)) 

    else: # people share different locations (latitude / longitude)
      pass

    return distance
```

This is my function that groups the people:

```
def group_people(all_persons, max_distance_parameter):

    assert len(all_persons) % 9 == 0
    all_persons.set_index("id", drop=False, inplace=True)

    all_persons["host"] = np.nan
    all_persons["group"] = np.nan

    Streufaktor = 0.0001 
    max_distance = max_distance_parameter
    group_number = 0
    group = []
    for index, candidate in all_persons.iterrows():
        if len(group) == 3:
            for person in group:
                all_persons.at[person["id"], "group"] = group_number
            group_number += 1
            group = []

        if len(group) == 0:
            group.append(candidate)
        else:
            for person in group:
                distance = calculate_distance(
                    candidate["latitude"],
                    candidate["longitude"],
                    person["latitude"],
                    person["longitude"],
                    candidate['floor'],
                    person['floor']
                )
                distance = distance 

                if 0 < distance <= max_distance:
                    group.append(candidate)
                    break
```

Next, I apply the function to the dataframe and look at the result:

```
group_people(all_persons,4)

all_persons
```

**This is what I get:**

[image]

In yellow you see what was going wrong (see problem definition above).

How can I fix this? (please check the linked Google Colab)

Comment: That is quite a long question. Does it need to be that long for people to recreate the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it does. Since I do not know what is going wrong,  I had to write this long question. However, I was trying to explain it very carefully and linked a Google Colab file

Comment: First suggestion to you: Don't do `math.sin/cos`. Look for haversine function on this site that uses `np.sin/cos...` which are vectorized.