# Assign people which have different locations to a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, distance

I have a pandas dataframe with people who live in different locations (latitude, longitude, floor number). I would like to assign 3 people to a group. The groups should be numbered from 1 to n. Important: These 3 people share **different** locations in terms of latitude, longitude and floor. This means, at the end of this process, every person is assigned to one particular group. My dataframe has the length of multiples of 9 (e.g 18 people).

**Example:**

Here is my dataframe:

```
array_data=([[ 50.56419  ,   8.67667  ,   2.       , 160.       ],
   [ 50.5740356,   8.6718179,   1.       ,   5.       ],
   [ 50.5746321,   8.6831284,   3.       , 202.       ],
   [ 50.5747453,   8.6765588,   4.       , 119.       ],
   [ 50.5748992,   8.6611471,   2.       , 260.       ],
   [ 50.5748992,   8.6611471,   3.       , 102.       ],
   [ 50.575    ,   8.65985  ,   2.       , 267.       ],
   [ 50.5751   ,   8.66027  ,   2.       ,   7.       ],
   [ 50.5751   ,   8.66027  ,   2.       ,  56.       ],
   [ 50.57536  ,   8.67741  ,   1.       , 194.       ],
   [ 50.57536  ,   8.67741  ,   1.       , 282.       ],
   [ 50.5755255,   8.6884584,   0.       , 276.       ],
   [ 50.5755273,   8.674282 ,   3.       , 167.       ],
   [ 50.57553  ,   8.6826   ,   2.       , 273.       ],
   [ 50.5755973,   8.6847492,   0.       , 168.       ],
   [ 50.5756757,   8.6846139,   4.       , 255.       ],
   [ 50.57572  ,   8.65965  ,   0.       ,  66.       ],
   [ 50.57591  ,   8.68175  ,   1.       , 187.       ]])

all_persons = pd.DataFrame(data=array_data) # convert back to dataframe

all_persons.rename(columns={0: 'latitude', 1: 'longitude', 2:'floor', 3:'id'}, inplace=True) # rename columns
```

[image]

How can I create this column? As you can see, my approach doesn't work correctly.

- This was my approach: [Google Colab Link to my solution](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EDjZ97mOu1qYU3ZzocuaXWerPUdTqMrK)

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Is the example not enough? I included a link to the full code example on Google Colab. I wanted to keep the question as short as possible. Otherwise people will ignore my question. I tried it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820697/grouping-people-in-pandas-dataframe-with-customized-function

Comment: We expect your question to be self-contained: keep in mind the purpose of this site.  Off-site links are rarely acceptable; images of critical data are rarely acceptable.

Comment: Sure, I think you are right. Do you want me to show my complete solution? If yes, this is what I did in the link I posted above. In the current post, I only posted the data and what I want to do with it. I thought this is the best way to deal with it

Comment: No, I merely asked you to follow the posting guidelines to which I linked.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = ()
temp += (pd.concat([df.loc[users group 1]], keys=[1], names=['group']),)
temp += (pd.concat([df.loc[users group 2]], keys=[2], names=['group']),)
temp += (pd.concat([df.loc[users group 3]], keys=[3], names=['group']),)

df = pd.concat(temp)
```

Of course you can do this in a loop and locate the users you need in a more elegant way.

Comment: Thank you Dimitris. But how do I know which users to put in a group? I need to find a way, to group only these people who have different locations. As far as I can see this, it is not considered in your solution.

Comment: Mea culpa, didn't read properly what the problem was.

In that case you could maybe use the .duplicated() function and get the indices of the users that have the same lat/lon coordinates.

Then you can group the users according to these indices.